# Jtable values duplicating the last value

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Im developing java desktop application for my college assignment. I have encounter a problem while i'm loading values to the Jtable. I used following code to load values. It makes duplicate entries. Can you please help me to get rid of this issue?

```
 private void LoadSupplierTable() {
    clearTable((javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel) tblSupp.getModel());
    javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel dtSupp = (javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel) tblSupp.getModel();
    Vector ver = new Vector();
    try {
        ResultSet resO = null;
        String sqo = "select id,name from supplier";
        Connection coo = DataBaseConnection.getDbConnection();
        PreparedStatement pso = coo.prepareStatement(sqo);
        resO = pso.executeQuery();
        while (resO.next()) {

            ver.add(resO.getInt("id"));
            ver.add(resO.getString("name"));
            dtSupp.addRow(ver);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Go into your database and query the same and see what you get.

Comment: Also you should close the Connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare the vector inside the while loop... just copy paste the following code

```
 private void LoadSupplierTable() {
    clearTable((javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel) tblSupp.getModel());
    javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel dtSupp = (javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel) tblSupp.getModel();

    try {
        ResultSet resO = null;
        String sqo = "select id,name from supplier";
        Connection coo = DataBaseConnection.getDbConnection();
        PreparedStatement pso = coo.prepareStatement(sqo);
        resO = pso.executeQuery();
        while (resO.next()) {
            Vector ver = new Vector();
            ver.add(resO.getInt("id"));
            ver.add(resO.getString("name"));
            dtSupp.addRow(ver);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```